# Core Web Vitals Assessment: Failed

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

There is a new feature in PageSpeed Insights that shows you the experience of real users. Now I checked one of my websites with this feature on mobile and I got this message:

> "Core Web Vitals Assessment: Failed Computed from the Core Web Vitals
> metrics over the latest 28-day collection period. Learn more"

Why is PageSpeed returning me this answer? It seems all ok in Google Search Console under Core web vitals.

Comment: They may have just changed the message. They normally need a certain amount of data before they will show this. Do you happen to know where the "learn more" link goes as I would imagine that will answer your question and will be useful information for others.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Now I understand. The link goes to this site https://web.dev/vitals/

Comment: Does the Core Web Vitals page in Search Console show that all the URLs are "good"?

Comment: Yes, but the website must have enough interaction and Google Search Console must have enough data.

Answer (score 1):

Core Web Vitals result is based on 3 metrics below

1. Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)
2. First Input Delay (FID)
3. Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)

All 3 metric's score is divided into 3 categories - Good, Needs Improvement and Poor.
If any of these 3 metric is not having 'Good' score, the overall results is shown as 'Failed'.
Check the metrics score just below the 'Failed' text, and find out which metric score needs to be improved.